# When I use array modifier to the bezier curve, the last part of the curve was not covered

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

[image]

I was trying to make ice cream, the array object doesn't cover the full curve, whatever I do the last part is not covered. I tried scaling, deleting the last vertices of curve but none covered till the last segment.

Comment: could you share your file so that we understand what's happening?

Answer (score 3):

Since your shape is uniform along length, consider using the star as a bevel.
Then you don't need the array modifier, and you have overall better control.

1. Convert your star shape to a curve (*Mesh > Convert to > Curve*)
2. Select the spiral, and choose your star shape as a Bevel object
3. Adjust to your needs
   [image]

Comment: If you fancy some ice-cream, you can taper it, too ! :)  Either with Alt-S, or a taper curve

Answer (score 2):

Is it slipping off the other end? Try <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.

[image]